# mySql get total number of registered users by date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which inputs new registered users like this

```
mytable
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | timestamp           | name |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 1  | 2014-06-03 00:02:40 | john |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 2  | 2014-06-03 00:02:41 | sue  |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 3  | 2014-06-03 00:02:42 | fran |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 4  | 2014-06-02 00:02:40 | mark |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 5  | 2014-06-02 00:02:41 | tim  |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

I would like to organize by date, the total number of users. This works when i hard code the date

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE timestamp LIKE '%2014-06-03%'
```

**Q:** How would i get the entire table by date the number of registered users?
here is my attempt but this gives me the 2 columns that i need but the count(id) returns 1

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(id)
FROM mytable
WHERE timestamp >= "2014-01-01" 
AND timestamp < DATE_ADD("2015-01-01", INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(id)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

since your timestamps are really timestamps and contain hour/minute/second data, you can't directly group on it - you'd be grouping by hh:mm:ss as well. So you group by `DATE(timestamp)`, which will extract the date portion (yyyy-mm-dd) and group by that only.